# Django MySQL Join to increase performance

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance, django-queryset

I am searching for medical items

I have 10 areas with 10 tables each containing medical dispensaries and 10 more tables with each table consisting of medical items available at those dispensaries.

Now I am searching a medical item among all these dispenaries

for each area, I am getting objects

```
  a_list = Washington_dispensaries.objects.all()
```

then I am searching whether this particular item is available in each dispensary

```
if category:
    a_lists = []
    for dispensary in a_list:
        items = dispensary.washington_dispensaries_item_set.filter(item__product_type__name = category)

        if items:
            result_cat_items.append(items)
            a_lists.append(dispensary)
    a_list = a_lists
```

It is taking 15 seconds to complete this query for all 10 regions.

If I write code in PHP, I would use MySQL join to make the query faster. Now how do I query faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already doing two joins, to item and product_type. So just do one more: instead of getting the dispensaries separately, do it as part of the filter. It's hard to give exact syntax without seeing your models, but something like:

```
DispensaryItem.objects.filter(dispensary__location='Washington', item__product_type__name=category)
```